# VAIO VGN-N220E screen resolution just 1024x768. when it should be 1280x800.

Tags: windows-8

help me please, my computer is VAIO VGN-N220E, 15". i have problem with my screen resolution, after i use this computer a while, then i shutdown, when i turn on my computer, the screen not turn on, so i can't see the boot.
after boot and into the windows the screen resolution just 1024x768. 
when it should be 1280x800. 
i check in Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution. limited 1024x768. i try to advance setting --> list all modes, its just 1024 by 768, true color (32 bit), 60 hertz..

thanks before..

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to reinstall the latest copy of your graphics card drivers. Visit the support page and download the latest copy of the video card drivers:

http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=VGNN220E&LOC=3&session_id=7afd5718902c71d9541290ca5443eab8